# Using categorical_crossentropy for only two classes

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, cross-entropy

Computer vision and deep learning literature usually say one should use `binary_crossentropy` for a binary (two-class) problem and `categorical_crossentropy` for more than two classes. Now I am wondering: is there any reason to not use the latter for a two-class problem as well?

Comment: There are already some good threads on this topic: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260505/machine-learning-should-i-use-a-categorical-cross-entropy-or-binary-cross-entro
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357541/what-is-the-difference-between-binary-cross-entropy-and-categorical-cross-entrop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `categorical_crossentropy`:

  - accepts only one correct class per sample
  - will take "only" the true neuron and make the crossentropy calculation with that neuron
- `binary_crossentropy`:

  - accepts many correct classes per sample
  - will do the crossentropy calculation for "all neurons", considering that each neuron can be two classes, 0 and 1.

A 2-class problem can be modeled as:

- 2-neuron output with only one correct class: `softmax + categorical_crossentropy`
- 1-neuron output, one class is 0, the other is 1: `sigmoid + binary_crossentropy`

---

Explanation

[image]

Notice how in categorical crossentropy (the first equation), the term `y_true` is only 1 for the true neuron, making all other neurons equal to zero.

The equation can be reduced to simply: `ln(y_pred[correct_label])`.

Now notice how binary crossentropy (the second equation in the picture) has two terms, one for considering 1 as the correct class, another for considering 0 as the correct class.