# Keras Why binary classification isn't as accurate as categorical calssification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to create a model which can tell whether there are birds in an image or not.

I was using categorical classification to train the model to recognize Bird v.s. Flowers, the results turned to be very successful in terms of recognizing these 2 classes.

BUT, when I change it to Binary Classification to detect the existence of birds in an images, the accuracy dropped dramatically.

> The reason why I changed to use Binary classification is that if I
>   provided a dog to my Categorical Classification trained model, it
>   recognized the dog as a bird.

btw, here is my data set structure:

Training:
5000 images for birds and 2000 images for not-birds

Validating:
1000 images for birds and 500 images for not-birds

[image]

**Someone said, the inblanced dataset will also cause problems. Is it true?**

**Could someone please point out where I get wrong in the following code?**

```
def get_num_files(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return 0
    return sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(path)])

def get_num_subfolders(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return 0
    return sum([len(d) for r, d, files in os.walk(path)])

def create_img_generator():
    return ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
        rotation_range=30,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True
    )

INIT_LT = 1e-3
Image_width, Image_height = 299, 299
Training_Epochs = 30
Batch_Size = 32
Number_FC_Neurons = 1024
Num_Classes = 2

train_dir = 'to my train folder'
validate_dir = 'to my validation folder'


num_train_samples = get_num_files(train_dir)
num_classes = get_num_subfolders(train_dir)
num_validate_samples = get_num_files(validate_dir)

num_epoch = Training_Epochs
batch_size = Batch_Size

train_image_gen = create_img_generator()
test_image_gen = create_img_generator()

train_generator = train_image_gen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(Image_width, Image_height),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    seed = 42
)

validation_generator = test_image_gen.flow_from_directory(
    validate_dir,
    target_size=(Image_width, Image_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=42
)

Inceptionv3_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
print('Inception v3 model without last FC loaded')

x = Inceptionv3_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(Number_FC_Neurons, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

# model = Model(inputs=Inceptionv3_model.input, outputs=predictions)
v3model = Model(inputs=Inceptionv3_model.input, outputs=predictions)
# Use new Sequential model to add v3model and add a bath normalization layer after
model = Sequential()
model.add(v3model)
model.add(BatchNormalization()) # added normalization
print(model.summary())

print('\nFine tuning existing model')

Layers_To_Freeze = 172
for layer in model.layers[:Layers_To_Freeze]:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[Layers_To_Freeze:]:
    layer.trainable = True

optizer = Adam(lr=INIT_LT, decay=INIT_LT / Training_Epochs)
# optizer = SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=optizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

cbk_early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', mode='max')

history_transfer_learning = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples,
    epochs=num_epoch,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps = num_validate_samples,
    class_weight='auto',
    callbacks=[cbk_early_stopping]
)

model.save('incepv3_transfer_mini_binary.h5', overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True)
```

Comment: Use ```sigmoid``` instead of ```softmax``` in last Dense layer for binary classification.

Comment: thanks @VivekMehta I will give it a try and update once it's done. thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Categorical

- Use `Num_Classes = 2`
- Use one-hot-encoded targets (example: `Bird = [1, 0]`, `Flower = [0, 1]`)
- Use `'softmax'` activation
- Use `'categorical_crossentropy'`

## Binary

- Use `Num_Classes = 1`
- Use binary targets (example: `is flower = 1 | not flower = 0`)
- Use `'sigmoid'` activation
- Use `'binary_crossentropy'`

Details here: [Using categorical_crossentropy for only two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216024/using-categorical-crossentropy-for-only-two-classes/59217175#59217175)

Comment: hi Daniel, thanks a lot for your answer. I am new to AI field, could you please give me some code to demo what does it mean -> Use binary targets? I have folders structure like: train/birds, train/notbirds, validate/birds, validate/notbirds.  Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Hi, if my assumption is correct, I have updated my code accordingly and started my training. My observation is the accuracy is really low. it has trained 450/1200 yet the accuracy only got 32%. Whereas previously, I observed that the accuracy was really high. Should I increase the size of my dataset ?

Comment: Your `y_train` must be shaped `(samples, 1)`, with values `0=not bird` and `1=bird`.  If you are using a keras `ImageDataGenerator`, use `class_mode='binary'` (I don't know what will be the result of this, though, you must check what the generator is outputting)

Comment: If you were good with categorical, why do you want to change to binary?

Comment: hi @Daniel, could you please refer back to my code about how to set ```y_train``` to be the shape you mentioned? coz in my code, it seems that I do not need to provide y_train.  Also where should I use the class_mode? do you mean loss='binary_crossentropy' in model.compile()?

Comment: hi @Daniel, as to why I use Binary instead of Categorical, I have updated my question, the answer of your question is in the quoted sentence.

Comment: Changing to binary will not solve the dog problem. That is lack of enough examples to avoid overfitting.

Comment: cool, how to solve it? By adding more non-bird images??? or change to other algorithm???

Comment: Yes, more non-bird images, not exactly in quantity, but in a variety of different things.

Comment: hi @Daniel, could you please refer back to my code about how to set ```y_train``` to be the shape you mentioned? coz in my code, it seems that I do not need to provide ```y_train```. Also where should I use the class_mode? do you mean loss='binary_crossentropy' in model.compile()?

Comment: `class_mode = 'binary'` in the `ImageDataGenerator`. But you need to verify if bird will be 0 or 1 yourself.

Comment: hi @Daniel, I don't understand how can I verify if bird will be 0 or 1. You can see that, from my code there is no need to specify 0 or 1. Could you please elaborate your meaning? thanks